# Ethminer not working with pool getting no speed

Tags: mining, ethminer

If I execute the following `./ethminer -G` mining seems to work fine...

`Time: 00:00
  m  10:41:51|          Speed   3.15 Mh/s    gpu/0  1.89  gpu/1  1.26  [A0+0:R0+0:F0]`

But when I try to run through a pool `./ethminer --farm-recheck 200 -G -S eu1.ethermine.org:4444 -O <address>.myrig` I get

```
  ✘  10:44:20|cl-0      Creating DAG buffer failed: clCreateBuffer -61
  ✘  10:44:20|cl-0      OpenCL Error: clEnqueueWriteBuffer -38
 cl  10:44:20|cl-1      Build info: <program source>:329:9: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and 'const uint' (aka 'const unsigned int')
                if (i == thread_id)
      ~ ^  ~~~~~~~~~
<program source>:364:9: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and 'const uint' (aka 'const unsigned int')
                if (i == thread_id)
      ~ ^  ~~~~~~~~~

 cl  10:44:20|cl-1      Creating light cache buffer, size 36961984
 cl  10:44:20|cl-1      Creating DAG buffer, size 2365580416
  ✘  10:44:20|cl-1      Creating DAG buffer failed: clCreateBuffer -61
  ✘  10:44:20|cl-1      OpenCL Error: clEnqueueWriteBuffer -38
....
Time: 00:00
  m  10:45:00|          Speed   0.00 Mh/s    gpu/0  0.00  gpu/1  0.00  [A0+0:R0+0:F0]
```

Why am I getting no speed in the pool?